# Problemas con DateTime al comparar

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo una consulta en BD y tengo problemas.

Tengo esta parte de código:

```
var retorno = (from p in Database.Programaciones
                           join sts in Database.SubTiposSenalizacion on p.SubTipoSenalizacionId equals sts.Id

                           where

                               ((PKHasta == 0 && PKDesde == 0) ||
                                ((p.PKDesde < PKHasta && p.PKHasta > PKDesde) ||
                                 (p.PKDesde > PKHasta && p.PKHasta < PKDesde)))
                               &&
                                  p.FechaInicio <= fechaHasta && p.FechaFin >= fechaDesde
```

El problema lo tengo con la última comparación:

```
 p.FechaInicio <= fechaHasta && p.FechaFin >= fechaDesde
```

Os explico, yo cojo la fecha de programaciones (FechaInicio) y me dice algo parecido a esto:  5/1/2008 8:30:52  la comparo con FechaHasta que me da la fecha (5/1/2008 9:30:52)

Yo quiero compararlas de tal forma que ignore las horas. Y no sé como hacerlo. Ya que necesito mostrar las fechas del mismo día es decir necesito que esto:

`p.FechaInicio == fechaHasta` y me enseñe todas las programaciones que son de la fecha que yo le he pasado a fechaHasta. ( Fecha hasta lo he creado así `DateTime fechaHasta = DateTime.Now;` )

Espero explicarme bien..

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder validar que dos [`DateTime`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.datetime?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.DateTime);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) tengan la misma fecha, bastaría con comparar su propiedad [`Date`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.DateTime.Date);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8)

Yendo a tu ejemplo,

```
DateTime fechaInicio = DateTime.Parse("5/1/2008 8:30:52");
DateTime fechaHasta = DateTime.Parse("5/1/2008 9:30:52");
```

Utilizando la propiedad date, se generaría un nuevo [`DateTime`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.datetime?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.DateTime);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8), con la fecha, pero con horas, minutos y segundos en 0

Por ejemplo

```
Console.WriteLine(fechaInicio.Date);
Console.WriteLine(fechaHasta.Date);
```

Produciría la siguiente salida:

> `5/1/2008 00:00:00`
>
> `5/1/2008 00:00:00`

Por lo cual, si comparamos las fechas ahora, valdrá [`true`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/true-literal) independientemente del horario que haya tenido el [`DateTime`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.datetime?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.DateTime);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) original

```
Console.WriteLine(fechaInicio.Date == fechaHasta.Date);
```

La salida sería

> `True`

Comment: muchas gracias!!

He descubierto otra forma que es más rápida que es:  

DbFunctions.TruncateTime(p.FechaInicio) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(fechaHasta)